# How to add query parameter to existing remote method in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two models, `user` & `order`, a user can have multiple orders. So I can use `GET /users/{id}/orders` to fetch all orders belongs to that user.

I am wondering how can I add a query parameter to the HTTP request. for example `GET /users/{id}/orders?terminated=true`.

There is no filed called `terminated` in the database, I only store the `terminatedTime`, so I also need to do calculation.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [where filter](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter) for your queries. If you had a boolean field called `terminated`, the following would have worked:
`/users/{id}/orders?filter={"where":{"terminated" : true}}`

Assuming that terminatedTime is a Date field, the below URL should find orders for a user with a terminatedTime after 16-March-2016.

`/users/{id}/orders?filter={"where":{"terminatedTime" : {"gt": "2016-03-16T00:00:00.000Z"}}}`

Note: I had used the StrongLoop API Explorer to try similar queries on my sample application. Depending on where you use it, the double-quotes may or may not be necessary.

Comment: I dont have to field called `terminated` in db. I only have terminatedTime, but the comparision does not work in my case, since I only need to check whether it has value or not.

Comment: This might work: `/users/{id}/orders?filter={"where":{"terminatedTime" : {"neq": null}}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the query string in your model this would work.

```
var loopback = require('loopback');

module.exports = function(User) {
var findOne = User.findOne;

User.findOne = function(filter, cb) {
    var context = loopback.getCurrentContext(),
        terminated = context.active.http.req.query.terminated;

        //order processing logic
```